# Does the number of available PCIe lanes affect M.2 speed?

Tags: pci-express, m.2

### Situation

I'm currently looking to use SBCs to fill a few server roles I want available on my home network. 
While looking at different SBC options I came across **KHADAS**, a group that sells SBCs that have M.2 compatability. Which I would love to have for a few services, even if I dont need them.

### Background

KHADAS has a few different SBC options, I've narrowed my interest to the VIM3 Pro or the Edge+Captain.

The **Edge+Captain** has 4x PCIe Lanes for M.2 through the Captain attachment, but it also costs more and includes a bunch of extra device inputs that I dont want/need.

The **VIM3 Pro** on the other hand has 1x PCIe Lane, but doesnt have the extra unwanted inputs, and also includes a built in SoC that specializes in ML processes.

### Question

My question is how do I determine the speed of the M.2 with only 1 PCIe lane available?
Will it be different from one with all 4 lanes?
I'm having trouble finding good source information, I'd really appreciate any help you guys can give me.

### Reference

**SBC** - single board computer (Raspberry Pi, LattePanda, Asus Tinkerboard, etc)
**M.2** - SSD form factor, for this particular question it references the NVMe standard of M.2.
**PCIe** - PCI-express or peripheral component interconnect express, is a interface standard.
**KHADAS** - a company that produces ABC's similar to raspberry pi’s
**VIM3** - a model of KHADAS SBC
**Edge+Captain** - a model of KHADAS SBC plus an extension board.
**ML** - machine learning
**SoC** - system on a chip, in this case refers to the ML chip that is similar in architecture to a GPU, but has a more refined set of processes.

Comment: You will have to explain your acronyms.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia article on [M.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2):

> Computer bus interfaces provided through the M.2 connector are PCI Express 3.0 (up to four lanes)

Digging a little further; some text from a [cited article](https://www.thessdreview.com/daily-news/latest-buzz/understanding-m-2-ngff-ssd-standardization/):

> Only the single ‘M’ keyed SSD can reach those lightning fast speeds that we have seen in the Samsung XP941, and will be evident in SSDs containing the LSI SandForce SF3700 flash controller. This is because only the single ‘M’ keyed connector connects by PCIe X4.  A single ‘M’ Keyed connector can also be used for SATA, but that would make as much sense as throwing the body of a Ferrari on a Ford Focus.

So it would seem the answer to your question is yes--more lanes will be faster--but not at all sure how to test.  Note that the M.2 controller will need to support it.  Due to all the "key" types and the fact that M.2 seems to be able to provide connectivity other than PCIe (such as USB, etc.) depending on the motherboard, you will definitely need to do your homework.

Honestly maybe no way to really tell due to all the possible hardware combinations without real-world testing.

If these are ARM based SBCs make sure CPU or network chipset won't be a bottleneck.  For example you could have superfast M.2 x4 SSD but if it's accessible through a USB 2.0 Gigabit Ethernet adapter there's no point.